# How to redirect from a view in one app to a view in another?

Tags: django

I am trying to build a job-board type of website. Right now I have user authentication (login, logout, register, password change, etc) in one app (`account`) and the `job` model and all other views/templates in another app(`job`).

To have the user log in, I used the views found in `django.contrib.auth`(this is `account/urls.py`):

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
]
```

In the `job` app I have created a `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name = 'dashboard'),
]
```

Upon logging in, I would like the user to be redirected to this `dashboard` URL/view found in the `job` app. How can I do this? I know that if I just put the `dashboard` view/url into the `account` app all I would need to do is add this to settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
```

But, how can I redirect to a view in another app?

Final note: I separated this into two apps in the first place because I've read that is good practice, but am not sure if it's needed here.

Comment: Using `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'` should work, whichever app the URL is in. If you have `app_name` in the `job/urls.py`, then you need to include the name too, e.g. `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'job:dashboard'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

Comment: The `reverse_lazy` isn’t actually required here, Django will automatically reverse the URL if you provide a URL name.

Answer (score 1):

in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('job:dashboard')
```

Comment: If you put `job:dashboard'` then you need to add `app_name = 'job'` to `job/urls.py`.

Answer (score 1):

This only works for redirection once logged in.

[settings.py]:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
```

If you want to redirect urls from any app to another, you must use static tags.

[file.html]

```
{% load static %}
```

and then:

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">
```